# Creating simple pages for SharePoint-2013 remotely from WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint-2013

I have no experience working with share point. I have a simple C# WPF application that should connect to SharePoint server and programatically create some pages based on layouts or update existing ones. The sharepoint server is not installed on my machine. I am using SharePoint client dlls locally from

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI

The only steps that is done and working is connecting with credentials, getting the list of folders and pages. I have some difficulties on creating and reading the content of the pages. So, what is the best way of doing it and is it possible to do it remotely?

I was trying to add server side libraries and come up with similar problem in a below question.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505754/c-sharp-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sharepoint-library) is saying that

> If you are using SharePoint dll's it will only work on a machine with SharePoint installed.

This [link](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/09/17/create-publishing-pages-sharepoint-2010-programmatically/) have good example of how to do it but i can't get necessary classes.

Comment: It looks like the libraries you mention modify a local instance of SharePoint. But you can certainly accomplish what you want: if you control the server, write a web service that uses this library, then call it from the client. Maybe SharePoint has a service like that already. If none of that is possible, you can always do it with web requests / tcp. If there is a way to do something as a human user, then there is always a way to do it in code, unless there is some kind of captcha involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are developing a *client* WPF application you could consider the following client-side APIs:

- Managed Client Object Model (CSOM)
- [RESTful Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- [SharePoint SOAP Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Since you mentioned in question that you've already installed [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585), below is demonstrated how utilize CSOM in WPF application.

### How to manage a Publishing pages using SharePoint 2013 CSOM API

SharePoint 2013 introduced [support for publishing pages in SharePoint 2013 CSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing(v=office.15).aspx), the following class demonstrates how to create and read publishing pages:

```
class PagesManager
{

    public static ListItemCollection LoadPages(ClientContext ctx)
    {
        var pagesList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
        var pageItems = pagesList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
        ctx.Load(pageItems);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        return pageItems;
    }



    public static void CreatePublishingPage(ClientContext ctx, string pageName,string pageLayoutName)
    {
        var pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(ctx, ctx.Web);
        var pageInfo = new PublishingPageInformation();
        pageInfo.Name = pageName;
        pageInfo.PageLayoutListItem = GetPageLayout(ctx,pageLayoutName);
        var publishingPage = pubWeb.AddPublishingPage(pageInfo);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }


    public static ListItem GetPageLayout(ClientContext ctx,string name)
    {
        var list = ctx.Site.GetCatalog((int)ListTemplateType.MasterPageCatalog);
        var qry = new CamlQuery();
        qry.ViewXml = string.Format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", name);
        var result = list.GetItems(qry);
        ctx.Load(result);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        var item = result.FirstOrDefault();
        return item;
    }
}
```

### WPF app

**Prerequisites**: make sure all the required SharePoint CSOM assemblies are referenced in WPF project as demonstrates on picture below

[image]

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="SPManager.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Pages" Height="350" Width="525" Name="PagesWindow">
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid  Name="gridPages" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Page"  Binding="{Binding Path=PageLink}" ContentBinding="{Binding Path=PageName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Creation Date" Binding="{Binding CreationDate}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Create Page" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="PageCreate_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Load pages**

```
 private void LoadPages()
 {
     using (var ctx = GetClientContext())
     {
        var items = PagesManager.LoadPages(ctx).Select(i => new
        {
            CreationDate = (DateTime)i["Created"],
            PageName = i["FileLeafRef"],
            PageLink = i["FileRef"].ToString()
        });
        gridPages.ItemsSource = items;
    }
}
```

**Create a publishing page**

```
private void PageCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var ctx = GetClientContext())
    {
        PagesManager.CreatePublishingPage(ctx, "Hello from WPF.aspx", "BlankWebPartPage.aspx");
    }
}
```

where

```
private static ClientContext GetClientContext()
{
    var webUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebUrl"]);
    //var userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
    //var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
     return new ClientContext(webUri);
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**Update**

How to create a publishing page and specify page properties:

```
public static void CreatePublishingPage(ClientContext ctx, string pageName,string pageLayoutName,IDictionary<string,object> properties)
{
    var pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(ctx, ctx.Web);
    var pageInfo = new PublishingPageInformation();
    pageInfo.Name = pageName;
    pageInfo.PageLayoutListItem = GetPageLayout(ctx,pageLayoutName);
    var publishingPage = pubWeb.AddPublishingPage(pageInfo);
    var pageItem = publishingPage.ListItem;
    foreach (var p in properties)
    {
        pageItem[p.Key] = p.Value; 
    }
    pageItem.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Usage

```
var pageItemProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
pageItemProperties["PublishingPageContent"] = "<h1>Hello from WPF!</h1>";
pageItemProperties["Title"] = "Hello from WPF!";
PagesManager.CreatePublishingPage(ctx, "Hello from WPF.aspx", "BlankWebPartPage.aspx", pageItemProperties);
```

### References

- [Choose the right API set in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- [NET client API reference for SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193041%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for solution Vadim! I had similar solution for that recently, there was the same steps. Can you please suggest the way how to set the title and content of the created page Vadim?

Comment: Thanks Vadim, it works fine for me. Can you please also show a good way how to edit/update existing pages?

Comment: @Mirzodaler, could you please post a separate question for that and i'd be glad to answer it ;)

Comment: I think I found solution for that, thanks for response.